# Double slash string becomes single slash inside the function

Tags: python, string, exec

I am trying to read a file using 'exec' command in python. Hence I am defining a function known as 'importing_data'. The function takes input the path of the folder from where the data needs to be read.

Printing Path is coming with double backslash.

```
print(path)
```

'C:\\Users\\evarxxx\\Desktop\\Raw_Data'

```
def importing_data(path,var):
    data_file_list=list_of_files(path)
    print(data_file_list)
    Data_Raw=[0]*len(data_file_list)
    order={'Aug':0,'Sep':1,'Oct':2,'Nov':3,'Dec':4,'Jan':5,'Feb':6,'Mar':7}
    data_so=pd.DataFrame()
    for i in data_file_list:
        mon= i.split(".")[0][:3]
        if(mon=='Aug'):
            continue
        ext=i.split('.')[1]
        dictt={'csv':'pd.read_csv','xlsx':'pd.read_excel'}

        command=dictt[ext]+"('"+path+'\\'+i+"')"
        print(command) 
        return command
        temp=exec(command)
        return temp
```

But when I am printing the path inside the function it is coming with single backslash.

pd.read_csv('C:\Users\evarxxx\Desktop\Office Work\Lead Segmented Time\New_Data\NewTechniques\Raw_DataDecember.csv')

And giving the below mentioned error:-

(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

(Here data_file_list=['August.xlsx', 'December.csv'])

I have even tried replacing

```
path = path.replace("\\", '\\\\');
command=dictt[ext]+"('"+path+r'\\'+i+"')"
```

But in that case in temp none type is getting read instead of a dataframe

Here I have two questions

1) Why double backslash is differently printed inside and outside of the function

2) How can I read using exec the csv files inside the folder

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the function definition of list_of_files()?

I would suggest you to iterate over your files in this manner:

```
import os

def list_of_files(path):
    fileList = list()
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        fileList.append(os.path.join(path,filename))
    return fileList
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend always using `os.path.join()` when opening files inside directories.
2. Read 1

Here's an example:

```
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\evarxxx\\Desktop\\Raw_Data'
nested_dir = 'New_Data'
filename = 'Raw_DataDecember.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, nested_dir, filename)
```

also, for obtaining path of current working directory (where your code is) use `os.getcwd()` - it's a good way to get a reference point of where your files are.

Comment: using the above mentioned code i am getting error

**(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape**

Comment: @VarunRathi paste here the command please. Also, review and accept the editing suggestion for your question, it is very hard to ready and understand as is

Comment: print(command) (Inside the function)
**pd.read_csv('C:\Users\evarxxx\Desktop\Office Work\Lead Segmented Time\New_Data\New Techniques\Raw_Data\December.csv')**

Comment: @VarunRathi try making this :  `pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\evarxxx\Desktop\Office Work\Lead Segmented Time\New_Data\New Techniques\Raw_Data\December.csv')`

Comment: ```filename = i

        path=os.path.join(path, filename)
        
       
        command=dictt[ext]+ "('" + path + "')"

        print(command)```
This is how I am making the command variable(inside the function). So where should I change?

Comment: here **path** have been formed by using the approach as you have mentioned in the answer

Comment: One More thing I have noticed that when I am directly executing pd.read_csv(path) then it is working fine but when I am trying to use the command expression and using exec() then it is creating problem

Answer (score 0):

1. As in [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) exec works as :  If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed. Hence different behaviour inside and outside exec.
2. exec doesn't return anything so you have to initialize within the command passed to exec

   `exec('''df = pd.read_csv('\your\file\path.csv')''')`